# memory leak - metrics-meter-tick-thread and New I/O client worker

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, titan

I am running spring-mvc application. When i was closing `Tomcat` server, it shows

```
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [metrics-meter-tick-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [metrics-meter-tick-thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

and this one :

```
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O client worker #1-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

SEVERE: The web application [/anant] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.jboss.netty.util.CharsetUtil$2] (value [org.jboss.netty.util.CharsetUtil$2@5db3978d]) and a value of type [java.util.IdentityHashMap] (value [{UTF-8=sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder@39a2da0a}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

this one don't know which jar is related with may be `netty`

when i explored jars dependency i saw that there are two `metrics-core` jars:

```
metrics-core:2.2.0 (used by `datastax`)
metrics-core:3.0.1 (used by `Titan`)
```

I am attaching all snaps to make it more clear. So what is the solution ????

I am using

`jdk1.7`
`cassandra-driver-core-1.0.4`
`titan-0.4.4`
`cassandra-1.2.2`
`tomcat-7.0.34`

[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late with this. I had the same issue and eventually found the solution. The problem is that the metrics 2.2 JAR, (which spawns these threads) uses the `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()` method, as suggested by Oracle. This class is in the `java.lang` package, so it will be loaded centrally by the **VM** and not for each module. So, since the Metrics package will only shut these threads down by itself on a **VM** exit (via adding a shutdown-hook), the **classloader** that loaded this package will let the `MXBeans` specified through the package linger on on the module's unload. What makes this even worse is that **classloader** that loaded the **war** file will also stay loaded on the **VM**, which (transitively) will also include any classes loaded in the module and any static state.

You can call `Metrics.shutdown()` manually, that sometimes solves the problem. I did have some exotic problems with that solution (sometimes the threads still stayed around after this, but I have a very peculiar setup and didn't want to waste any more time on this issue).

Answer (score 0):

Check what started metrics-meter-tick-thread* threads , either your webapp or some library. And stop the thread before you shutdown application.
See Tomcat wiki [link](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection) explains how it creates a memory leak. Also it explains how uncleaned ThreadLocal variables causes memory leaks.

> **Threads spawned by webapps**
>
> If a webapp creates a thread, by default
> its context classloader is set to the one of the parent thread (the
> thread that created the new thread). In a webapp, this parent thread
> is one of tomcat worker threads, whose context classloader is set to
> the webapp classloader when it executes webapp code.
>
> Furthermore, the spawned thread may be executing (or blocked in) some
> code that involves classes loaded by the webapp, thus preventing the
> webapp classloader from being collected.
>
> So, if the spawned thread is not properly terminated when the
> application is stopped, the webapp classloader will leak because of
> the strong reference held by the spawned thread.

Comment: It is started by library only so i can't stop it.

Comment: see if updated version of library is available or report this bug.

Comment: how? can u give any reference or example